# site error in Plone while log in

Tags: plone

I am new user. I am getting an error while entering the localhost page as site error.

In terminal it shows as

```
zeoserver: . . . . . . . . . . . 
daemon manager not running
client1: . 
daemon process started, pid=3838
client2: . 
daemon process started, pid=3844
```

In Localhost error as

```
An error was encountered while publishing this resource.

Sorry, a site error occurred.

Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 235, in publish_module_standard
    Module zope.publisher.skinnable, line 46, in setDefaultSkin
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 860, in setstate
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 914, in _setstate
    Module ZODB.serialize, line 612, in setGhostState
    Module ZODB.serialize, line 605, in getState
    Module copy_reg, line 48, in _reconstructor

TypeError: ('object.__new__(PersistentResourceDirectory) is not safe, use Persistence.Persistent.__new__()', <function _reconstructor at 0xb7792d14>, (<class 'plone.resource.directory.PersistentResourceDirectory'>, <type 'object'>, None))
```

Please suggest me how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this discussion [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.zope.plone.user/113866). Did you remove any egg from the buildout without uninstalling it previously?